# Telerik RadWindowManager 

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I use Telerik radWindowManager to display alert windows.
I have code like this:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="window1" runat="server" ReloadOnShow="true" 
EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" OnClientClose="javascript:alert('test')">
...
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

The problem is when I use this code without "OnClientClose" it works fine but when I add "OnClientClose" the alert is not displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: Could be just not seeing the close function -You need to give more details. Are you using a master page?What does your on close function contain?where is it located?(on master, in js file, after being called etc)

Answer (score 3):

The OnClientClose attribute takes *pointer* to a JS method, not a call.

Which is why Nima M's solution works

From the Telerik website, RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX > Documentation > [Client-Side Events](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-client-side-events.html):

> The RadWindow control has a number of properties whose value is the name of a javascript function that executes when specific client-side events occur.

That is, not inline JavaScript. The equivalent properties on the `RadWindowManager` class work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably write a separate method to handle OnClientClose:

```
    <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="window1" runat="server" ReloadOnShow="true" 
    EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" OnClientClose="OnClientCloseHandler">
    ...
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>

<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="rcbModal" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function OnClientCloseHandler(radWindow) {
                //Do Domething Here
            }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```